# TransactionValidityTranslationError: What's the valid interval for time/slot transation

Tags: cardano-api

I suddenly encountered this error, I had never encountered before. I was using (Protocol params and era history configuration from 2 weeks ago. It used to work for months before.

```
TransactionValidityTranslationError (TimeTranslationPastHorizon "PastHorizon {
pastHorizonCallStack = [(\"runQuery\",SrcLoc {srcLocPackage = \"ouroboros-consensus-0.1.0.0-a216910c01eb3712c5487a4b54690aeafd473fd59e5beff964ae947cd0bb7174\", srcLocModule = \"Ouroboros.Consensus.HardFork.History.Qry\", srcLocFile = \"src/Ouroboros/Consensus/HardFork/History/Qry.hs\", srcLocStartLine = 430, srcLocStartCol = 44, srcLocEndLine = 430, srcLocEndCol = 64}),(\"interpretQuery\",SrcLoc {srcLocPackage = \"ouroboros-consensus-0.1.0.0-a216910c01eb3712c5487a4b54690aeafd473fd59e5beff964ae947cd0bb7174\", srcLocModule = \"Ouroboros.Consensus.HardFork.History.EpochInfo\", srcLocFile = \"src/Ouroboros/Consensus/HardFork/History/EpochInfo.hs\", srcLocStartLine = 45, srcLocStartCol = 50, srcLocEndLine = 45, srcLocEndCol = 68}),(\"interpretQuery'\",SrcLoc {srcLocPackage = \"ouroboros-consensus-0.1.0.0-a216910c01eb3712c5487a4b54690aeafd473fd59e5beff964ae947cd0bb7174\", srcLocModule = \"Ouroboros.Consensus.HardFork.History.EpochInfo\", srcLocFile = \"src/Ouroboros/Consensus/HardFork/History/EpochInfo.hs\", srcLocStartLine = 39, srcLocStartCol = 9, srcLocEndLine = 39, srcLocEndCol = 52}),(\"epochInfoSlotToRelativeTime_\",SrcLoc {srcLocPackage = \"cardano-slotting-0.1.0.0-7618dff6992469ca39863ffbcc2ebdde043b2a836c21f9a4d8d0ba8fe2c8209e\", srcLocModule = \"Cardano.Slotting.EpochInfo.API\", srcLocFile = \"src/Cardano/Slotting/EpochInfo/API.hs\", srcLocStartLine = 62, srcLocStartCol = 9, srcLocEndLine = 62, srcLocEndCol = 37}),(\"epochInfoSlotToRelativeTime\",SrcLoc {srcLocPackage = \"cardano-slotting-0.1.0.0-7618dff6992469ca39863ffbcc2ebdde043b2a836c21f9a4d8d0ba8fe2c8209e\", srcLocModule = \"Cardano.Slotting.EpochInfo.API\", srcLocFile = \"src/Cardano/Slotting/EpochInfo/API.hs\", srcLocStartLine = 125, srcLocStartCol = 40, srcLocEndLine = 125, srcLocEndCol = 70}),(\"epochInfoSlotToRelativeTime_\",SrcLoc {srcLocPackage = \"cardano-slotting-0.1.0.0-7618dff6992469ca39863ffbcc2ebdde043b2a836c21f9a4d8d0ba8fe2c8209e\", srcLocModule = \"Cardano.Slotting.EpochInfo.API\", srcLocFile = \"src/Cardano/Slotting/EpochInfo/API.hs\", srcLocStartLine = 62, srcLocStartCol = 9, srcLocEndLine = 62, srcLocEndCol = 37}),(\"epochInfoSlotToRelativeTime\",SrcLoc {srcLocPackage = \"cardano-slotting-0.1.0.0-7618dff6992469ca39863ffbcc2ebdde043b2a836c21f9a4d8d0ba8fe2c8209e\", srcLocModule = \"Cardano.Slotting.EpochInfo.API\", srcLocFile = \"src/Cardano/Slotting/EpochInfo/API.hs\", srcLocStartLine = 91, srcLocStartCol = 30, srcLocEndLine = 91, srcLocEndCol = 63}),(\"epochInfoSlotToUTCTime\",SrcLoc {srcLocPackage = \"cardano-ledger-alonzo-0.1.0.0-8d084ba3551393bc3a51af041b759b56dfc986c4f3d9b8ac5ecfc8ac9b696582\", srcLocModule = \"Cardano.Ledger.Alonzo.TxInfo\", srcLocFile = \"src/Cardano/Ledger/Alonzo/TxInfo.hs\", srcLocStartLine = 233, srcLocStartCol = 9, srcLocEndLine = 233, srcLocEndCol = 41})], 
pastHorizonExpression = Some (EPair (ERelToAbsTime (ERelSlotToTime 
  (EAbsToRelSlot (ELit (SlotNo 73626947))))) (ESlotLength (ELit (SlotNo 73626947)))), 
pastHorizonSummary = [
 EraSummary {eraStart = Bound {boundTime = RelativeTime 0s, boundSlot = SlotNo 0, boundEpoch = EpochNo 0}, eraEnd = EraEnd (Bound {boundTime = RelativeTime 89856000s, boundSlot = SlotNo 4492800, boundEpoch = EpochNo 208}), eraParams = EraParams {eraEpochSize = EpochSize 21600, eraSlotLength = SlotLength 20s, eraSafeZone = StandardSafeZone 4320}},
 EraSummary {eraStart = Bound {boundTime = RelativeTime 89856000s, boundSlot = SlotNo 4492800, boundEpoch = EpochNo 208}, eraEnd = EraEnd (Bound {boundTime = RelativeTime 101952000s, boundSlot = SlotNo 16588800, boundEpoch = EpochNo 236}), eraParams = EraParams {eraEpochSize = EpochSize 432000, eraSlotLength = SlotLength 1s, eraSafeZone = StandardSafeZone 129600}},
 EraSummary {eraStart = Bound {boundTime = RelativeTime 101952000s, boundSlot = SlotNo 16588800, boundEpoch = EpochNo 236}, eraEnd = EraEnd (Bound {boundTime = RelativeTime 108432000s, boundSlot = SlotNo 23068800, boundEpoch = EpochNo 251}), eraParams = EraParams {eraEpochSize = EpochSize 432000, eraSlotLength = SlotLength 1s, eraSafeZone = StandardSafeZone 129600}},
 EraSummary {eraStart = Bound {boundTime = RelativeTime 108432000s, boundSlot = SlotNo 23068800, boundEpoch = EpochNo 251}, eraEnd = EraEnd (Bound {boundTime = RelativeTime 125280000s, boundSlot = SlotNo 39916800, boundEpoch = EpochNo 290}), eraParams = EraParams {eraEpochSize = EpochSize 432000, eraSlotLength = SlotLength 1s, eraSafeZone = StandardSafeZone 129600}},
 EraSummary {eraStart = Bound {boundTime = RelativeTime 125280000s, boundSlot = SlotNo 39916800, boundEpoch = EpochNo 290}, eraEnd = EraEnd (Bound {boundTime = RelativeTime 157680000s, boundSlot = SlotNo 72316800, boundEpoch = EpochNo 365}), eraParams = EraParams {eraEpochSize = EpochSize 432000, eraSlotLength = SlotLength 1s, eraSafeZone = StandardSafeZone 129600}},
 EraSummary {eraStart = Bound {boundTime = RelativeTime 157680000s, boundSlot = SlotNo 72316800, boundEpoch = EpochNo 365}, eraEnd = EraEnd (Bound {boundTime = RelativeTime 158544000s, boundSlot = SlotNo 73180800, boundEpoch = EpochNo 367}), eraParams = EraParams {eraEpochSize = EpochSize 432000, eraSlotLength = SlotLength 1s, eraSafeZone = StandardSafeZone 129600}}]}")
```

What's the reason for the error? At given time, how do I find out the size of valid time horizon?